# Mongoose callback function not firing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have seen this problem come up a number of times here but none of the solutions worked for me. Here is the code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var db = mongoose.connection;
var dbUrl = 'mongodb://george:paradamodei123@ds037234.mongolab.com:37234/mydb';

var perosonSchema = new Schema({
    id: Number,
    name: String,
    age: Number,
    stories: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Story"}]
});

var storySchema = new Schema({
    _creator: {type: Number, ref: "Person"},
    title: String,
    fans: [{type: Number, ref: "Person"}]
});

var Story = mongoose.model("Story", storySchema);
var Person = mongoose.model("Person", perosonSchema);

db.on('error', function () {
  console.log('there was an error communicating with the database');
});

mongoose.connect(dbUrl);

  console.log('connected!');

var aaron = new Person({id: 0, name: "Aaron", age: 32});
    console.log("created aaron");

aaron.save(function(err) {


    console.log("no error");


    var story1 = new Story({
        title: "Once upon a time",
        _creator: aaron.id
    });

    story1.save(function (err){
        if(err) return console.log("err");
    });
});
    console.log("finished");
    db.close();
    process.exit();
```

So, when I run the script, it logs that it connected, it created aaron, SKIPS "no error" and just logs "finished". It's worth mentioning that I am a complete begginer at mongoose and node in general, so sorry if this is an easy question, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

It is because aaron.save is asyncron call, it calls, but your program dont waiting for response, and just continues working, and exits process. And when aaron is saved, process is exited;
To fix it, just call finished and db.close in callback function
Something like this

```
aaron.save(function(err) {
    console.log("no error");
    var story1 = new Story({
        title: "Once upon a time",
        _creator: aaron.id
    });

    story1.save(function (err){
        if(err) return console.log("err");

        console.log("finished");
        db.close();
        process.exit();
    });
});
```

In this way your code will save aaron. After saving will create story, save, and after saving close db and exit process

Read more about nodejs callback here [here](http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/javascript-callbacks/)